# bootstrap text area starts from center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have this form with bootstrap , in which there is a text area, in which text starts from middle. i have just copied the default, and tried to many things to starts text from initial position but not worked,

[image]

```
<form name="messageform" action="" method="POST" id="messageform">


                    <div class="small-10 columns">
                        <label style="color:black;"> Subject*</label>
                        <input class="span12" type="text" name='subject' id="subject" placeholder="Enter your email subject" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Input Message Subject between 10 to 80" data-validation-required-message="Please enter subject"  required>

                    </div>

                    <div class="small-10 columns" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <label style="color:black;"> Email Content*</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control span12" name="content" id="content" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter your email content" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" minlength="5"
              data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Input Message Content between 50 to 500" required></textarea>                    </div>
                    <div class="small-10 columns" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <label style="color:black;"> Reply Email Address*</label>
                        <input class="span8" type="email" name="reply_email" class="form-control" id="reply_email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-6 columns" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send the Message" id="_send" name="_send">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send the Message" id="_cancel" name="_cancel">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action">
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-6 columns" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="emails[]" id="emails" value="">
                    </div>
                    {% if form.errors %}
                    <p class="error">Sorry, please input the required text...</p>
                    {% endif%}
                    <div class="small-6 columns">

                    </div>
                </form>


$('#messageform').validate({
        rules: {
            subject: {
                minlength: 10,
                required: true
            },
            content: {
                minlength: 10,
                required: true
            },
            reply_email: {
                required: true
                email: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://www.bootply.com/KWiW4nd2fq

Comment: but not on mine page.

Comment: @BeatAlex is there some kind of line-height issue?

Comment: try this to add  white-space: normal; in textarea css

Comment: it was ok before, but as long as i put validation in it, this problem occurs. then by removing validation facing same issue.

Comment: not now worked by putting white-space: normal;

Comment: No, I didn't add any css.

Comment: please share your demo in js fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69806/discussion-between-jenti-dabhi-and-muhammad-taqi-hassan-bukhari).

Comment: it work fine on Js Fiddle, but not on my page.

Comment: was this resolved?